# How can I enforce scoping on singular resources using Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a few singular resources in my app, e.g.:

```
# routes.rb
MySite::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :thing
end

# things_controller.rb
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    load_thing
  end

  def update
    load_thing
    if @thing.update_attributes(thing_params)
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

  private

  def load_thing
    @thing ||= current_user.thing
  end

  def thing_params
    params.require(:thing).permit(...)
  end
end
```

I'm wondering how to enforce policy scoping using Pundit (`before_action :verify_policy_scoped` has been set in `ApplicationController`).

I'm not sure how to form my policy scope for singular resources, i.e.:

```
# thing_policy.rb
class ThingPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      # What to do here...
      # scope => ?
    end
  end
end

# things_controller.rb
def load_thing
  # ...and what to do here
  @thing ||= policy_scope(...)
end
```

According to [Pundit's docs](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#scopes):

> ...the method `resolve`...should return some kind of result which can be
>   iterated over.

However, with singular resources, this iterability clause isn't really valid and there is no AR-style scope as such... just a single record.

Anyone have any suggestions for how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Scoping is generally performed on the `index` action to restrict the base set of records the user can access before filtering is applied. For individual records, you should `authorize` them instead.

In any case, you are already scoping `@thing` to `current_user`

Would suggest to limit `before_action :verify_policy_scoped` to `only: [:index]`